Python + Selenium で h2 要素の位置を特定して、ある部分だけの h3 要素を取得したい
ソースコードが以下のようになっているサイトがあり、Python + Seleniumで　
h2タグの id="bb" 配下にある h3タグの yy1,yy2 の要素だけを取得したいです。
親クラスやセクションで特定できないため、xpathなどで指定できません。
htmlのh2要素のidだけで位置を特定して、そのid=bbとid=ccの間のh3タグだけ取得する方法はありますでしょうか？
<h2 id = "aa"> XXXXX </h2>
<h3> xx1 </h3>
<h3> xx2 </h3>
<h2 id = "bb"> XXXXX </h2>
<h3> yy1 </h3>
<h3> yy2 </h3>
<h2 id = "cc"> XXXXX </h2>
<h3> zz1 </h3>
<h3> zz2 </h3>


CSS セレクタを利用して以下の様に書くことができます。
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2#bb ~ h3:has(~ h2#cc)')
for elm in elements:
    print(elm.get_attribute('outerHTML'))

# <h3> yy1 </h3>
# <h3> yy2 </h3>


ありがとうございます！上手くいきました。
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2#bb ~ h3’)だけでも取得することができました。

'h2#bb ~ h3' だけですと、zz1 と zz2 も含まれることになります。（手元の環境 Python 3.12.3/Selenium 4.23.0/chromedriver 125.0.6422.141 ではそうなります）

ありがとうございます。zz1,zz2含まれることあるといけないので、教えていただいた方法でやります。
